# Change bootstrap navbar default background color

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to change the color of my navbar which I've created using bootstrap. I've tried other suggestions I have seen on this site, but it does not seem to work for me, so I'm not sure what I'm missing. I have set the background color using !important but that does not seem to have any effect.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Restaurant</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>

    <div id="content">
        <div id="header"></div>

        <nav class="navbar navbar-default center navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light">
            <div class="navbar-nav mx-auto">
                <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="#">About <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Menu</a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>

    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
#header{
    background-image: url(../images/askItalian.jpg);
    background-size: auto;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: top center;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    margin: 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    justify-items: center;
    align-items: center;
}
h1{
   font-family: Damion;
   font-style: italic;
   font-weight: bold;
   color: white;

}

.navbar{
    position: fixed;
    height: 3em;
    width: 100%;
}

.navbar-default{
    background-color: red !important;
}
```

Comment: Move your CSS file after Bootstrap's

Answer (score 0):

Delete the "bg-light" class from the  tag and it'll work

Answer (score 0):

You could load the bootstrap first. So the positions of the two  elements in the .

Or just remove the bg-light class of the  , because that class has a !important